# Why gcc splits error message along several lines?

Tags: c, gcc

Sometimes `gcc` displays a single error/warning message in several lines.
Not a big deal, but it looks a little strange (and ugly) to me.

```
server_inc.c: In function ‘prepareForConn’:
server_inc.c:101: error: ‘filename’ undeclared (first use in this function)
server_inc.c:101: error: (Each undeclared identifier is reported only once
server_inc.c:101: error: for each function it appears in.)
```

Specially because the location (`server_inc.c:101: error:`) is prepended, so it looks as if there were many errors.

Is there some way to change this? I'm using `gcc 4.4.7` on Linux.

Comment: There is no GCC 4.4.17, did you mean 4.4.7? There is an error message line wrapping mode (`-fmessage-length`), but that's supposed to be disabled by default. Which options are you passing to GCC?

Comment: Yes, I fixed the version, thanks. I'm running a plain `gcc -Wall prog.c`... `-fmessage-length` option has no effect

Comment: **Current GCC is [GCC 5.3](https://gcc.gnu.org/gcc-5/)** in end of december 2015 (and start of 2016). You really should **upgrade your** (old) **compiler**. And the current one has better support for recent standards C++11, C++14, C11... and improved diagnostics and optimizations; you could even compile GCC 5.3 from its source code.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch 4.4.7 is the current available version in Centos-6

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Starting with GCC 4.5, the second message appears on a single line, and is prepended by "note" rather than "error":

```
$ cat test.c
int main() { x=3; }

$ gcc-4.5.4 -c test.c
test.c: In function ‘main’:
test.c:1:14: error: ‘x’ undeclared (first use in this function)
test.c:1:14: note: each undeclared identifier is reported only once for each function it appears in
```

With GCC 4.4, I can reproduce the behaviour you're seeing, and that does look like a bug without any way to work around it. If possible, please upgrade your compiler.

Answer (score 0):

Probably because default terminal size has a historical width of 80 columns, see [this](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/148677/why-is-80-characters-the-standard-limit-for-code-width) question.

Given this, GCC has a behavior which by default could follow this rule, taken from [here](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Diagnostic-Message-Formatting-Options.html):

> `-fmessage-length=n`
>
> Try to format error messages so that they fit on lines of about n characters. **The default is 72 characters for g++ and 0 for the rest of the front ends supported by GCC**. If n is zero, then no line-wrapping is done; each error message appears on a single line.

You could specify `-fmessage-length=0` to remove line wrapping.

Comment: That's what I thought too, but it isn't it, GCC 4.4.7 wraps like that even with `-fmessage-length=0`.

Comment: No effect (at least on that particular message) for me.